# Wrong output of intersectsLine from Line2D in Java

Tags: java

Why does this code:

```
Line2D line1 = new Line2D.Double(464.9298111721873, 103.78661133348942, 684.8391765253534, -155.44752172931908);

Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(414.16903384086487, 163.62456359144306, 393.52528378472925, 187.95988300984624);

line1.intersectsLine(line2);
```

return true?

Clearly, x coordinates of lines are way apart, and they do not intersect. I drew them onto a swing panel, and they are apart, but look like they are collinear. Is this the problem?
I tried testing on simple collinear lines (like (1, 3, 4, 3), (6, 3, 8, 3)), and it seemes to work fine.

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer : if it were lines, not lines segments, these lines would be overlapping...But `Line2D` are supposed to be line segments...Thus, these lines should be separated...

Answer (score 2):

[Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#intersects(double,%20double,%20double,%20double)) say that the method of the `Line2D` class:

```
public boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h)
```

tests if the interior of the [**`Shape`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) intersects the interior of a specified rectangular area. It uses the `Shape.intersects()` method for this, however the calculations to accurately determine this intersection are very expensive.

**This means that for some `Shapes` this method might return true even though the rectangular area does not intersect the `Shape`**.

Although you are using the method `itersectsLine()`, both `intersects()` and `intersectsLine()` use the **same expensive method** underneath the surface. The method is called `linesIntersect()` and is [**specified here**](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/geom/Line2D-source.html) on line 298

The [**`Area`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class performs more accurate computations of geometric intersection than most `Shape` objects and therefore can be used if a more precise answer is required. For instance:

```
boolean intersectionExists(Shape shape1, Shape shape2) {
   Area area1 = new Area(shape1);
   area1.intersect(new Area(shape2));
   return !area1.isEmpty();
}
```

Tested using your values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Line2D line1 = new Line2D.Double(464.9298111721873, 103.78661133348942, 684.8391765253534, -155.44752172931908);
    Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(414.16903384086487, 163.62456359144306, 393.52528378472925, 187.95988300984624);
    System.out.println("Lines intersect? " + intersectionExists(line1, line2));
}
```

Output:

```
Lines intersect? false
```

Comment: I'm not using Line2D.intersects, but Line2D.intersectsLine, which is implement quite differently (and, in a way bit unclear to me).

Comment: thanks! Still wondering thou why it thinks that such far-away lines do intersect.